# Trouble keeping image path's consistent with WebStorm dev Vx production

Tags: webstorm

I love using WebStorm for building html/css/JavaScript apps but one problem I have not been able to figure out is how to deal with paths to images on my `src` attribute of image tags.

I have (for example) a project path in WebStorm of `/documents/myproj/index.html` where I've opened the project at `/documents/myproj`. WebStorm sees the root of the project as `/myproj` but the URL created when I browse is `localhost/myproj/index.html`. When I publish the site it becomes `localhost/index.html` (on my public server).

Image `src` tags are a problem for me because in development, the WebStorm server wants `src=/myproj/1.jpg` and in production it wants `src=/1.jpg`.

Any suggestions for how to keep this straight between running in local mode with WebStorm's built-in simple web server and the published version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the host accordingly to make WebStorm serve your files using a different URL. See https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5532366#5532366 for some hints

Comment: @PeterKellner Please clarify what "example" you want to see.

Comment: What the new DNS entry might look like

Comment: @PeterKellner 1) Please use `@name` otherwise user will not get notified of your message (unless you are talking to the person who made the Answer); 2) in `hosts` file or your local DNS server? If second -- it depends on your DNS server syntax -- please refer to their docs; for "hosts" file -- examples should be listed in it already. In any case: `DESIRED_IP  DOMAIN_NAME`, for example: `127.0.0.1 my.fake.domain.com` or `192.168.0.4 myProject`